# Posting Image Media into or part of an article and load into a lightbox

Tags: nodes

I'm just starting into Drupal and have done some reading into fields and such. I have an article in which I would like to add some images, in one scenario a block of images at the bottom of the article. In Content Types > Articles > Manage fields I have added a field of type "image". When I add/edit an article, I am able to upload images, however I can not get any of the images to appear in my published article.

To be clear, I can get the images to display in the WYSIWIG editor, but want them to be displayed and "Clickable" so the image will open into some kind of lightbox.

I have tried changing display settings but nothing seems to get my images to appear this way. I must be missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Here is how the image field is configured.
[image: Image Field configuration]

Comment: That article explains how to post the image in the WYSIWIG editor - I can do that, but I want the images to appear on the bottom of the article(I can do with WYSIWIG editor, but want them clickable), clicking would bring up a lightbox with a larger image.

Comment: So tell us (and post a screenshot) of how you configured image field and it's display in your content type. Without this we can't quite know what you tried and what's wrong. Also, please edit additional info directly into question.